# Suppose $xe^y-5y=2x+14-2e^{-2}$ and $y(-2)=-2$. How to find $y'(-2)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Suppose $xe^y-5y=2x+14-2e^{-2}$ and $y(-2)=-2$. Find $y'(-2)$.

Just learning this and confused on how to solve, can someone show me the solution step by step?

Comment: I tried doing the implicit derivative but not sure if i'm doing anything right.

Comment: What's the result of your implicit derivative attempt? To avoid being closed, you might want to write in your post what you have done.

Comment: The derivative of $y(-2)$ is $y'(-2)$ so since $y(-2) = -2$ you are trying to find the derivative of $-2$. $$-2 = -2\times 1 = -2\times x^0$$ so now derive $x^0$ and multiply by $-2$. The answer is $-2\times 0\times x^{-1}$ which is just $0$. This implies that the derivative of *any* constant must be $0$, however I put this in a comment because I do not know if I am doing this entirely right. If you are looking at equations including $e^y$ then if you did not do what I just did, I could missing something or doing something incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.-You have $$F(x,y)=xe^y-5y-2x+(2e^{-2}-14)=0$$
Then $$y'(x)=\frac{2-e^y}{xe^y-5}$$ $$y(-2)=-2\Rightarrow y'(-2)=\frac{e^{-2}-2}{2e^{-2}+5}$$You can verify that it is truly the asked derivative plotting the curve and the tangent at the point $(-2,-2)$ using this derivative as pente.

Answer (score 2):

$$xe^y-5y=2x+14-2e^{-2}$$
Put $y = \ln t,$
 $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times \frac{dt}{dx}

\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac1t$$

So substituting into 1

$xt-5\ln t=2x+14-2e^{-2}$

Differentiating

$t+xdt/dx-5tdt/dx=2

dt/dx=(2-t)/(x-5)

dt/dx=(2-e^y)/(x-5)
dt/dx=(2-e^-2)/(-7)

dy/dt=1/t=1/e^y=e^2

dy/dx=e^2(2-e^-2)/-7

=-2(e^2-1)/7$
Merci